# Pseudocode for comparison counting algorithm

Tags: algorithm, sorting, pseudocode

**I'm working on a homework question for my algorithms class and I'm boggled by how this particular algorithm works. I already found the answer online so I'm not looking for answers, just some help working through the code step by step. From what I can figure out so far, the algorithm accepts an array of an unspecified length and through multiple iterations, sorts the numbers by comparing an individual element with smaller elements within the array. At the end of the iterations, it assigns each element a location index that specifies what order the elements should be arranged in to be in a non-decreasing order. But what I cannot figure out is how the second for-do loop start off the iteration after the first loop is completed? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated**

Question: Consider the algorithm for the sorting problem that sorts an array by counting, for each of 
its elements, the number of smaller elements and then uses this information to put the 
element in its appropriate position in the sorted array. Sort the following list of numbers, (60, 35, 81, 98, 14, 47):

```
Algorithm ComparisonCountingSort(A[0..n − 1], S[0..n − 1])
//Sorts an array by comparison counting
//Input: Array A[0..n − 1] of orderable values
//Output: Array S[0..n − 1] of A’s elements sorted in nondecreasing order

for i ← 0 to n − 1 do
     Count[i] ← 0

for i ← 0 to n − 2 do
     for j ← i + 1 to n − 1 do
          if A[i] < A[j]
               Count[j] ← Count[j] + 1
          else
               Count[i] ← Count[i] + 1

for i ← 0 to n − 1 do
     S[Count[i]] ← A[i]

return S
```

Comment: Can you format the code a bit better please? You don't need brackets if indentations are proper, but at the moment I can't tell if those are nested fors or what.

Comment: The second loop doesn't start after the first one is completed, the second for loop one is **nested** to the first one actually.

Comment: @Fallen, sorry for the confusion, I was referring to the second for-do loop that starts immediately after the first two lines (the first for-do loop in the algorithm) is completed

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. "How the second for-do loop start off the iteration after the first loop is completed?" -- what does that mean?

Comment: Since `n` isn't modified in any way by the first loop (and neither are the constants `0` and `2`), the second loop isn't affected in any way, so… why _wouldn't_ you expect it to be able to start off the iteration?

Answer (score 1):

The crux of this sorting algorithm is the realization that if a number `x` in the array has exactly `n` elements in the array that are smaller, then in the sorted array it should be the `n`'th element (in a zero-indexed array).

So what the algorithm wants to do is check for each element how many other elements are smaller. But then you end up checking each pair twice which is unnecessary. The second loop is built in such a way that each pair is compared exactly once.

The second loop, which is the double for loop can be visualized as follows, for the case where the length `N` is 4:

```
1st outer loop   | i ->  [0]
                 | j ->  [1] [2] [3]

2nd outer loop   | i ->  [1]
                 | j ->  [2] [3]

3rd outer loop   | i ->  [2]
                 | j ->  [3]
```

Here `i` and `j` are your loop iterators and the values between brackets are the values of the index they take on. Now you can clearly see that with this construction each pair is compared once

Comment: That actually does help but if it's not too much trouble, could you possibly get me started on the list {60, 35, 81, 98, 14, 47}? I don't even know where to begin

Comment: What do you mean get you started? You said you had the code and it worked

Comment: It was provided to us as a homework question and I have the solution to it which I found online but I'm trying to figure out how to actually apply the algorithm to the list. So I'm asking for help on how to start off the iterations and once I know how to do that I can figure out the rest on my own

Comment: @user2827137: This algorithm is simple enough to trivially turn into code in your favorite language, and then you can run it in a debugger, add some `print` statements, etc. That'll be a lot easier and more useful than trying to get someone on the internet to run the code manually for you.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for any assistance that was given but I was able to figure it out after working on it for awhile. In laymen's terms, you start with the first column which is the current i, and compare it to each column following it (which would be j in the comparison), and if i is greater than j, then i gets a 1. If j is higher, j gets a 1. After the first row which consists of all zeroes, the second row is iterated. Using 60 as i, you compare it to 35 which is the current j, since 60 is greater than 35, 60 gets a 1 (tally mark if you will). Then you compare 60 to 81 since that becomes the new j. Since 81 is higher than 60, 81 gets the tally mark. This continues on until the rest of the row is finished. In the next iteration, the next column becomes the new i, and the following will become the new j one after another. Rinse and repeat until all columns and rows are finished and you have a new index value for each element which you then is put in order.